# How to open popup modal present in parent component on clicking button present on child component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Parent and Child component

Parent Component : contains the modal

Child Component: contains button to toggle modal

how to open a modal on clicking button present in child component

Button to open modal inchild component

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="openModal()">Click to Open</button>
```

Modal in Parent Component

```
<b-modal
    id="bv-modal-lead"
    header-class="py-2 bg-primary text-white"
    body-class="p-0"
    hide-footer
    style="z-index:9999;"
    size="md"
    no-close-on-esc
    no-close-on-backdrop
    header-close-variant="light">
    <template v-slot:modal-title>Required Details</template>

    <div class="d-block p-0">
        <ChildCopmonent
            @openModal="clickToOpen"/>
        </div>
</b-modal>
```

//Parent

```
<script>
    export default {
        methods:{
            openModal(){
                this.$bvModal.show('bv-modal-lead')
            }
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to open parent modal from clicking button present in child component

Answer (score 0):

You can emit an event in child component and fetch it in the parent one.

So in the child component there should be `@click="$emit('openModalEvent')"` where `openModalEvent` is the event name (it can be `openModal` but remember it's an event not a method).

Now You can listen for `openModalEvent` event in the parent component - `@openModalEvent="openModal"` where `openModal` is a method to call.

Child

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="$emit('openModalEvent')">Click to Open</button>
```

Parent

```html
<b-modal
    id="bv-modal-lead"
    header-class="py-2 bg-primary text-white"
    body-class="p-0"
    hide-footer
    style="z-index:9999;"
    size="md"
    no-close-on-esc
    no-close-on-backdrop
    header-close-variant="light">
    <template v-slot:modal-title>Required Details</template>

    <div class="d-block p-0">
        <ChildCopmonent @openModalEvent="openModal" />
    </div>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.component('message', {
  template: '<div class="message" @click="handleClick">Click to Dismiss Message</div>',
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
        this.$emit('click')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showMessage: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMessage () {
        this.showMessage = !this.showMessage
    }
  }
})
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vyq75n0d/